# Machine learning book with robust linear algebra approach

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am looking for machine learning book - neural network, deep learning etc etc - that use linear algebra in a robust manner. I found satisfactory the old book of Simon Haykin : Neural Networks : A Comprehensive Foundation -1998.
Do you know if exist a text book recently released in the same trace? 
Many thanks

Comment: Gilbert Strang has a new book called [Linear Algebra and Learning from Data](https://math.mit.edu/~gs/learningfromdata/) that you might be interested in.

Comment: It seems an interesting book. I was wondering if it is worth to buy it or  something like The Elements of Statistical Learning https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/

Answer (score 1):

What about the [deep learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/)?

It has an entire chapter 2 on the linear algebra although reading it now some concepts are beyond what I learned in an elementary course in university.
The Deep Learning Book is known as a fundamental resource for DL and I guess where DL overlaps with ML, ie. neural networks.

Comment: Thank you . It is what I have in mind .-:)